# NUnit, Serilog and Datadog

Tags: .net-core, nunit, serilog, datadog

we are facing a problem using NUnit, Serilog, and Datadog.

## Our configuration

We are working with:

- .NET Core 3.1 (Visual Studio 16.5.4)
- NUnit + NUnit3TestAdapter
- Serilog + Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs

All packages are NuGet lastest.

## Serilog configuration

This is the Serilog configuration we are using:

```
DatadogConfiguration datadogConfiguration = new DatadogConfiguration()
{
  Url = "https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu",
  Port = 443,
  UseSSL = true,
  UseTCP = false
};

ServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
  .AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>()
  .AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog(
    new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    .Enrich.WithProcessName()
    .Enrich.WithProcessId()
    .Enrich.WithThreadName()
    .Enrich.WithThreadId()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "Serilog Test Application")
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
    .WriteTo.Debug(
      outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:o} {Level:u3}] [{MachineName}] [{ProcessName}:{ProcessId}] [{ThreadName}:{ThreadId}] [{Application}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{Exception}{Properties:j}{NewLine}")
    .WriteTo.File(
      path: "D:\\Temp\\LogFile.txt",
      outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:o} {Level:u3}] [{MachineName}] [{ProcessName}:{ProcessId}] [{ThreadName}:{ThreadId}] [{Application}] [{SourceContext}] {Message:lj}{Exception}{Properties:j}{NewLine}")
    .WriteTo.DatadogLogs(
      "API_KEY",
      source: "csharp",
      service: "test service (by code)",
      host: "Serilog test application",
      tags: new string[] { "TAG_1:VALUE_1", "TAG_2:VALUE_2" },
      configuration: datadogConfiguration)
    .CreateLogger()))
  .BuildServiceProvider();
```

## The test

We are testing this configuration both in debug run (F5 key in Visual Studio) and under the NUnit test environment (in Visual Studio).

## The problem

The problem we are facing is that while in debug run all work fine:

- Logs correctly arrive on Visual Studio Debug Output.
- Logs correctly arrive on file.
- Logs correctly arrive on Datadog.

when we run this code in the NUnit environment:

- Logs correctly arrive on Visual Studio Debug Output.
- Logs correctly arrive on file.

but **no logs arrive at Datadog**.

Checking the network stream with Fiddler we notice that while in debug run, logs are sent to Datadog, under the NUnit environment **logs are NOT sent to Datadog**.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: have you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: I guess not....

Answer (score 2):

I'm very sorry for this late answer.

After exchanging a bunch of emails with the Datadog support guys, it turned out that the solution is straightforward:

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
public virtual void Cleanup()
{
    logger.Dispose();
}
```

The `Dispose()` method force the sinks to gracefully close up and send the logs stored in cache.

Please note that the logs do not appear instantly in the Datadog console: allow a few seconds (to some minutes) for their systems to process the logs you send.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in the startup.cs.

```
var config = new DatadogConfiguration("https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu");
        Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .WriteTo.DatadogLogs("<Datadog_API_KEY>", configuration: config)
       .CreateLogger();
// Call this from anywhere in the app
Serilog.Log.Logger.Information("This is a test from session-start");
Serilog.Log.Logger.Error("This is a test from session-start");
```